# MetaSearch "undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class" for global bar search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, meta-search

I'm using fantastic MetaSearch by Ernie, but I'm having an annoying issue.

In my application.html.erb I have an search field, just like this one on top of StackOverflow page.

```
<%= form_for @search, :url => vagas_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :titulo_or_empresa_user_username_contains %>
    <%= f.submit "", :class => "search-button", :name => "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

The problem is that I don't have @search initialized in all actions of all controllers, so when I'm not at Vagas#index I get the "undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class" message.

What's the best solution for that?

============================================

Solution

```
<%= form_tag vagas_path, :method => :get, :id => 'vaga_search' do %>
    <%= text_field_tag 'search[titulo_or_empresa_user_username_contains]' %>
    <%= submit_tag "", :class => "search-button", :name => "submit", :id => 'search_submit' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Just fixed it using a form_tag instead of form_for.

Comment: Using 'form_for' with 'Search.new' instead of '@search' may have worked as well (not 100 percent sure though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would get this error if `@search` is set to `nil`. Ensure that this is not the case.

Comment: Yep. So how do I initialize @search in order to never be nil in any of my Controller's action's ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax:

```
<%= form_for(:object) do |obj| %>
```

In my case I was using the view to collect nested attributes from user inputs but this syntax also gets around this error message in other contexts.