# Rails Tutorial 10.2 - 6: "NoMethodError in Users#edit"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I've been walking through the Hartl tutorial for the first time and have been getting an error on Chapter 10 editing/updating users.  Following along, I >>should<< be able to at least view the user edit page, but keep getting the below error.  Have gone through everything a few times but can't seem to find the origin of my problem.  Note that this is my first time doing anything programming related so go slow with me.

Error

> undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Line being called out in error, from my user edit view

`<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>`

Edit method from Users controller

```
    def edit
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @title = "Edit user"
    end
```

A similar block of code is used in my user new view with no issues, and am at a loss why this would be returning nil and have tried with both new and existing users .  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue, it looks like this happens because your "edit" action isn't defined. Could it be you have either not saved the `user_controller` file or forgotten to define the "edit" variable?

Answer (score 0):

The error is a bit obscure. It is saying that `@user` in `<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>` is nil. It is likely that `@user = User.find(params[:id])` is not finding anything. It would be worth putting `Rails.logger.debug("Id: #{params[:id]}")` above `@user = User.find(params[:id])` and see what is being passed for `params[:id]`.

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147693/metasearch-undefined-method-model-name-for-nilclassclass-for-global-bar-sea) had a similar issue though not with the tutorial. The exception is coming from `form_for`.

Comment: Scott, thanks for the response.  Will try what you suggested and see what I see.  Just been at a loss trying to figure out why @user would be nil!